# Getting checkbox state in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as follows :

```
 import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import { filter_names } from './filterActions';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class fuel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            values: {}
        }
    }


    handleFuel(name, event){
        let checkbox = event.target.checked;
        let nValues = _.clone(this.state.values);
        nValues.type = name;
        nValues.active = checkbox;
        this.setState({values: nValues});
    }



    render() {
        const language = this.props.language;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="priceTitle" style={{padding: '5px 0'}}>{language.fuel}</div>
                <div className="transmissionValues">
                    {_.uniq(this.props.allCarsInTheList.map(i => i.fuel)).map((v, i) => {
                        return (<div key={i}><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleFuel.bind(this, v)} checked={true}/> <span>{v}</span></div>);
                    })}
                </div>
                {/*<div className="transmissionValues">
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleBenzine.bind(this)} checked={this.getFilterValues().checkboxBenzine}/> <span>Benzine</span>
                </div>*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm mapping through my data and depending on fuel field I'm rendering checkboxes. Thus, I do not want to change the code if my data is changed. But now I have  problem to get check if the checkbox is checked or not.

In handleFuel function I'm adding data to the state, and if checkbox is changed the state (`this.state.values`) should be something like `{type: "Diesel", active: "True"}`.

And then in the render I need somehow to get the state active. I tried with something like `let checkboxState = Object.keys(this.state.values).length > 0 ? this.state.values.filter(i => i.type === v).active : false;` , but it didn't worked.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

```
let allCarsInTheList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        listID: 3,
        make: "Audi",
        model: "Q5",
        desc: "2.0 CR TDi Comfortline BMT",
        price: 12484,
        mileage: 120021,
        fuel: "Diesel",
        engine: '105/77',
        chassis: "WAUZZZ4G4FN026103"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        listID: 3,
        make: "Audi",
        model: "Q5",
        desc: "2.0 CR TDi Comfortline BMT",
        price: 12484,
        mileage: 120021,
        fuel: "Benzine",
        engine: '105/77',
        chassis: "WAUZZZ4G4FN026103"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        listID: 3,
        make: "Audi",
        model: "Q5",
        desc: "2.0 CR TDi Comfortline BMT",
        price: 12484,
        mileage: 120021,
        fuel: "Diesel",
        engine: '105/77',
        chassis: "WAUZZZ4G4FN026103"
    }, {
        id: 4,
        listID: 3,
        make: "Audi",
        model: "Q5",
        desc: "2.0 CR TDi Comfortline BMT",
        price: 12484,
        mileage: 120021,
        fuel: "Diesel",
        engine: '105/77',
        chassis: "WAUZZZ4G4FN026103"
    }
]
```

Comment: How does allCarsInTheList looks like

Answer (score 0):

You're accidentally passing in `v` rather than event into your click handler. To help stop confusion, I'd add the bind in the `constructor`.

```
this.handleFuel = this.handleFuel.bind(this);
```

Then your checkbox becomes a bit easier to read too:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => this.handleFuel(v, e)} checked={true}/>
```

ps, should `checked={true}` be `defaultChecked={true}`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Boky You can try something like this, note this should work only when you have initial state from the start where you set the checkboxes to false or true. Because we run `this.isChecked()` as soon as the `componentDidMount` I suggest you take the state you can use `defaultChecked` for `"fake"` status.. Can't fully understand what's going on but from what I see this should take you where you want. Good luck

```
import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import { filter_names } from './filterActions';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class fuel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        values: {}
      };
      this.handleFuel = this.handleFuel.bind(this);
      this.isChecked = this.isChecked.bind(this);
    }

    handleFuel(name, event){
      let checkbox = event.target.checked;
      let nValues = _.clone(this.state.values);
      nValues.type = name;
      nValues.active = checkbox;
      this.setState({ values: nValues });
    }

    isChecked(name) {
      const { values } = this.state;
      let isChecked;
      const checkbox = values.find((c) => c.name === name);
      if (checkbox) isChecked = checkbox.active;
      return isChecked;
    } 

    render() {
        const { values } = this.state;
        const { language, allCarsInTheList } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="priceTitle" style={{padding: '5px 0'}}>
                {language.fuel}
              </div>
              <div className="transmissionValues">
                {_.uniq(allCarsInTheList.map(i => i.fuel)).map((name, i) => (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      onChange={(event) => this.handleFuel(name, event)}
                      checked={this.isChecked(name)}
                    />
                    <span>{name}</span>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```